# No data retrieved when using REQUIRES_NEW transaction inside another TRANSACTIONAL method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

Maybe this is an reccurent question but I'm not able to understand this problem:
Here's a simple code:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MainClass {

    @AutoWired
    private NestedService1 ns1; 

    public void mainMethod(){
       ns1.inner();
    }

}


@Service
public class NestedService1{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void inner(){
        //here retrieve some data from db with the EM
        Object1 obj1 = em.createQuery(query, Object1.class).getSingleResult();

        //Why obj1 is null ?
    }

}
```

But **obj1** is not setted correctly and an exception is thrown and if I use getResultList, the retrieved list is empty.

But when I remove the @Transactional annotation from MainClass, obj1 is setted correctly and everything works fine.

So why the EM associated in the NestedService1 class doesn't contain/manage any data ?
Please, please don't explain with EJB examples, that won't help, since I'm using Spring/JPA

Comment: have you read the docu ?  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW  "NOTE: Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to JtaTransactionManager, which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE)."

Comment: Yes I read it, and I understand that, but technically why still cannot fetch data while using the EM from the nested transaction ?

Comment: More description is neccessary, as you don't explain what you are querying for and why it wouldn't be there in your new transaction.   Ie can it see no data at all, or just not data added in the main transaction?   If you are inserting or making changes in the main transaction - the point of transactions is that changes made in them are not visible to everyone else until they are committed.  By using the REQUIRES_NEW, you are forcing your thread to be in its own transactional context, isolated from changes made in the large one